# Group entries per week where each column got specific date validation

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by, week-number

I am trying to group tickets per week in a year when data field X are between that week. The final result should be something like Week,Datefield1,Datefield2..

What I reached so far:

```
DECLARE @YearStartDate datetime
SET @YearStartDate = '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @YearEndDate datetime
SET @YearEndDate = '2016-04-24 00:00:00.000'

SELECT
Year(T.CreateDate) as 'Year',
'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, CreateDate) as varchar(2)) as 'Week',
Sum(CASE WHEN CreateDate BETWEEN @YearStartDate and @YearEndDate
    THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Created' 
FROM mytable AS T
GROUP BY Year(T.CreateDate),datepart(wk,T.CreateDate)
ORDER BY Year(T.CreateDate),datepart(wk, T.CreateDate)
```

Result:

```
Year        Week    Created
----------- ------- -----------
2016        Week 1      0
2016        Week 2      5
2016        Week 3      3
2016        Week 4      2
```

Goal:

```
Year        Week    Created    Schuduled    Closed
----------- ------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2016        Week 1       0          0          0
2016        Week 2       5          3          2
2016        Week 3       3          2          2
2016        Week 4       2          2          0
```

Suggestion?

```
SELECT
Year(..) as 'Year',
'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, ...) as varchar(2)) as 'Week',
Sum(CASE WHEN CreateDate BETWEEN @YearStartDate and @YearEndDate
    THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Created'
Sum(CASE WHEN ScheduledDate BETWEEN @YearStartDate and @YearEndDate
    THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Scheduled' 
Sum(CASE WHEN ClosedDate BETWEEN @YearStartDate and @YearEndDate
    THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Closed' 
FROM mytable AS T
GROUP BY Year(...)
ORDER BY Year(...)
```

Constraints: 
I can count the entries per week for one datafield but for several datafields (created,scheduled,pending,closed) I think I need to change the logic. Maybe create a inner join or left join against the same table.

I was wondering if you could give me some guidance on finding the right path. Thanks for taking the time to help me.
All the best.

Comment: Wouldn't changing your select to `SELECT
Year(T.Datefield1) as 'Year',
'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, Datefield1) as varchar(2)) as 'Week',
Sum(CASE WHEN Datefield1 BETWEEN @YearStartDate and @YearEndDate
    THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Created', Sum(CASE WHEN Datefield1 BETWEEN @YourSecondStart and @YourSecondEnd
    THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'scheduled' ` do the trick ?

Comment: Hi Nico. Thanks for your reply. Please find my suggestion draft above. My big headache is because I need to use different SUM CASE WHEN datefield1, SUMCASE WHEN datefield2.. for each week and year when my original query I only can retrieve datepart for one datefield...

Answer (score 0):

Right, join on other similar SELECTs for scheduled and closed should work. Something as

```
DECLARE @YearStartDate datetime = '2016-01-04 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @YearEndDate datetime = '2016-04-24 00:00:00.000';

SELECT CLR.*, SCH.Schuduled, CLS.Closed FROM
    (SELECT
        Year(T.CreateDate) as 'Year',
        'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, CreateDate) as varchar(2)) as 'Week',
        Sum(CASE WHEN CreateDate BETWEEN @YearStartDate and @YearEndDate THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Created' 
    FROM mytable AS T
    GROUP BY Year(T.CreateDate),datepart(wk,T.CreateDate)
    ) CRT

    JOIN
    (SELECT
        Year(T.ScheduleDate) as 'Year',
        'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, ScheduleDate) as varchar(2)) as 'Week',
        Sum(CASE WHEN ScheduleDate BETWEEN @YearStartDate and @YearEndDate THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Schuduled' 
    FROM mytable AS T
    GROUP BY Year(T.ScheduleDate),datepart(wk,T.ScheduleDate)
    ) SCH
    ON CRT.Year = SCH.Year
        AND CRT.Week = SCH.Week

    JOIN
    (SELECT
        Year(T.ClosedDate) as 'Year',
        'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, ClosedDate) as varchar(2)) as 'Week',
        Sum(CASE WHEN ClosedDate BETWEEN ClosedDate and @YearEndDate THEN 1 Else 0 End) 'Closed' 
    FROM mytable AS T
    GROUP BY Year(T.ClosedDate),datepart(wk,T.ClosedDate)
    ) CLS
    ON CRT.Year = CLS.Year
        AND CRT.Week = CLS.Week
ORDER BY Year, Week
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three different date columns.  One method would pre-aggregation along the dimensions and then use `full outer join`.  Alternatively, you can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
SELECT Year(dte) as [Year],
       'Week ' + datename(wk, dte) as [Week],
       Sum(Created) as Created,
       Sum(Scheduled) as Scheduled,
       Sum(Closed) as Closed
FROM ((SELECT createddate as dte, 1 as created, 0 as schedule, 0 as closed
       FROM mytable
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT scheduleddate as dte, 0 as created, 1 as schedule, 0 as closed
       FROM mytable
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT closeddate as date, 1 as created, 0 as schedule, 0 as closed
       FROM mytable
      ) 
     ) t
GROUP BY Year(date), datename(wk, dte)
ORDER BY Year(date), datename(wk, dte);
```

I would encourage a couple of things:

- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  Only use single quotes for string and date names.
- Do not use reserved works such as "year" for column or table names.

Also note the use of `datename()`.  This returns a string so no conversion is needed.